# maven import java swing awt working with jdk17 and the version of the library (org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:4.3)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have imported from maven what title of the question says
the problem is to the point where I get graphics from my canvas(awt one)
and add it to jpanel this does not seem to be drawed

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class CELSIUS {
    private JButton button1;
    private JPanel panel1;
    public java.awt.image.BufferedImage bf;
    public Canvas cnv;
    public JFrame jf;
    private boolean annadido=false;
    public CELSIUS() {
        panel1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseMoved(e);
                System.out.println("Hallo\n");
                
            }
        });


    }
    private void createUIComponents() {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        button1 = new JButton("OK");
        bf=new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        Graphics gc=bf.getGraphics();
       gc.setColor(Color.BLACK);

       gc.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
        cnv=new Canvas();
        cnv.setSize(100,100);
        gc.setColor(Color.white);
        gc.drawString("francisco",10,10);
        gc.dispose();




    }
        public static void main(String []args){

       JFrame jf=new JFrame();
       CELSIUS mycell=new CELSIUS();
       mycell.jf=jf;
       mycell.jf.setSize(500,500);
       jf.setContentPane(mycell.panel1);
       mycell.cnv.getGraphics().drawImage(mycell.bf,0,0,jf);



       jf.getContentPane().add(mycell.cnv);

       jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


       jf.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

so what happens
???
note: if I add it multiple times in the mouse move handler sometimes works as intended
showing a blinking Francisco on white over black background

Comment: 1) Don't use getGraphics() for custom painting. 2) Don't use a Canvas for custom painting. 3) Instead override the `paintComponent(...)` method of a `JPanel`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started. Note if you are just drawing to paint an image then an easy way is to use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Icons`.

Comment: tanks for the advice but in short i will add new features combining to bitmaps with xor operations lo get partial inversion of an image in a rich color environment but form now need this first phase working

Comment: `org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:4.3` is [tag:swt] - nothing to do with Swing or AWT

Comment: thanks i will remove it

Comment: ok erased and still working

Comment: *but for now need this first phase working* - which is why you have been given a link to the tutorial. You can't write a complex painting program if you don't understand the basics of doing custom painting.

Comment: thx i will try to remake the program following the official path

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right way:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.PanelUI;

import static javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.*;

public class main12 {
    public static void main(String [] a){
     mijpanel a1=new mijpanel();
     JFrame jmain =new JFrame("Hello world");
     jmain.add(a1);
     jmain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     a1.setVisible(true);
     jmain.pack();
     jmain.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
                SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
        a1.add(new Label("This is"));
        a1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseMoved(e);
                jmain.setTitle("Moving "+e.getX()+" "+e.getY());
            }
        });
    return;
    }





}
class mijpanel extends JPanel{
public
BufferedImage inner;
    public mijpanel(){
        super();
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(RAISED));
         inner=new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    }
    @Override
 public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
      return new Dimension(500,500);



 }
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
    /*System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
            SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());*/

        //System.out.println(getUI());
    if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
    {
        Graphics g3=inner.getGraphics();

        g3.setColor(Color.black);
        g3.fillRect(00,0,100,100);
        g3.setColor(Color.white);
        Font myfont1=g3.getFont();
       //System.out.println( myfont1.getFontName());
        g3.drawString("My text",0,20);

        g3.dispose();

    }
      g.setXORMode(Color.white);
      System.out.println(g.getColor());
      g.drawImage(inner,0,0,this);
      g.drawString("Custom painting",50,50);

     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     g.setXORMode(Color.white);
    g.drawString("To see ...and given color",150,150);
    g.setColor(Color.green);

     g.fillRect(50,80,200,200);


    //g.fillRect(50,80,200,200);
}
}
```

as you can see i have removed all unneccesary library dependences

Comment: when i draw in xor mode over background the color rgb=51 (background grey) doesnt seem to be taked into account yo do the three xor compostion(xor color background and pixel on which i drawed) only when it has another thing drawed on top.Why?